# What is this book about an obsidian pyramid?

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

Ok I have a very hazy memory of reading a book with an obsidian pyramid. I think I probably read it in the 90's but it could have been in the early 2000's.

There was something evil about the construction or existence of the pyramid, but other than that I can't remember anything else about the book.

Dream-Weaver by Jonathan Wylie comes to mind, I think maybe there was a pyramid under the salt? It was that kind of fantasy book anyway.

Comment: Hi :-) I have added the *novel* tag. If your book isn't a novel please shout!

Comment: Do you remember if it involved Aztec mythology?

Comment: I really do not remember much more than I've stated. I have read books which involved Aztec mythology though.

Comment: Warhammer Fantasy had the Black Pyramid of Nagash - not obsidian, iirc, but also made of black stone. And *very* evil. Not sure if it appeared in any non-game books, though.

Comment: Vague memories of something like this in one of Dorris Lessing's *Canopus in Argos* series.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I fear that there is not enough to go on here to identify a specific book.  However one book that fits the right time frame, and is definitely centred around the construction of an evil pyramid is "[Threshold](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/232021.Threshold)" by Sara Douglass.

The protagonist, Tirzah is an enslaved craftswoman with a special skill with glass.  The greedy Magi of Ashdod are building a giant pyramid that they intend to use to gain vast magical power & immortality.  They are using armies of slaves to build their pyramid (at least 8 generations so far).  When Tirzah touches the glass on the pyramid she can hear it scream to her.

Needless to say when, roughly half way through the novel, the pyramid is completed, it does not turn out the way that the Magi expected.

The novel was written in 1997.  The plot is centred on the construction of a pyramid, which is definitely evil both in the lives lost to build it, and the slaves sacrificed to power it.  The pyramid itself becomes alive in a sense (inhabited by an evil spirit).

All of those match.  But the pyramid is not described as being obsidian.  It is glass laid over stone.  Nevertheless it looks quite dark in the image shown here.  It seems possible to me that you remembered it as obsidian, especially since obsidian is volcanic glass.

[image: Cover of threshold around 2000]

Comment: Now I see the cover, I think this is most definitely it, thank you.

Comment: This pyramid was also in the DarkGlass Mountain trilogy, Sara Douglass's third Tencendor trilogy. Maybe the name of this trilogy also contributed to me thinking it was obsidian.

Comment: @DafyddNZ I read Threshold in ~2002, and suggested it because it was the only "evil pyramid" book I can remember.  I only found out that it had sequels yesterday when I looked it up to check the details.  Hitherto I always thought it was a stand-alone novel.  I might look up this trilogy one day.

Answer (score -4):

Could be the Crystal Shard, a forgotten realms book.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please explain the details of this book that make you think it's a match for the question?

Comment: The crystal obelisk in this book is sentient and evil. It uses the person who currently owns it, and mentally affects them to gain power. If possible it can outright mind control weaker minded people. It attracts armies of evil creatures to it. It also gains power from the sun. The heros of the story have to go against the army and it's owners supplemented powers, to destroy it.

Comment: @onetimeguesser I recommend you edit your original answer with the details you mention in your comment.